# Binary Search in C++ with array

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Here is an array with exactly 15 elements:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Suppose that we are doing a binary search for an element. Indicate any elements that will be found by examining two or fewer numbers from the array.

What I've got: as we are doing binary search, so the number found by only one comparison will be 7th element = 7. For two comparison, this leads to second division of array. That is, number found can be either 3 or 11.

Am I right or not?

Comment: Sounds correct to me, might want to add in the assumption that when splitting an even number array in half you are using the smaller of the 2 possible numbers to split on.

Comment: yes, this lead you for two comparison, but sometimes array won't be ordered, you may want to order it before.

Comment: Given the array in the problem description, it would actually be `4 8 12`.

Comment: `arr[7] = 8`, which may be leading to your confusion. You said the 7th element, you might mean the element at `7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost right, the first number is not seven but eight.

The others 2 will then be 4 and 12.

The correct answer would be 4, 8, 12

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

`I found the answer to be 8 that is the 7th element, the other elements found were  3.5th and 10.5th element of the sorted array. So, the next two numbers delved are 4 and 11.

explanation on how i got the answers.
    given array is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15

```
head=1
tail=15
middle= 0+14/2=7th element **0 is the index value of 1 and 14 is of 15**    
middle value turns to be 8 as it is the 7th element.

solving value for first half
head=1
tail=8
middle= 0+7/2=3.5 or 3rd element **0 is the index value of 1 and 7 is of 8**

middle value now turns to be 4 as it is the 3rd element.

solving value for second half
head=8
tail=15
middle= 7+14/2=10.5 or 10th element  **7 is the index value of 8 and 14 is 
of 15**

middle value now turns to be 11 as it is the 10th element of the array`
```

> Blockquote

Comment: An explanation on how you get your answer, would be nice for ohter users.